# Column Names Linked to New Item Form

Tags: 2013

This is my first post here, and I am rather new to Sharepoint, so I apologize if this is at all unclear.

I have a datasheet view, and each item where the first column is (column is called "DB") is hyperlink to the appropriate edit form. This is also the case when clicking on the actual column names as well.

I have searched for an answer for this problem, but I can't seem to find a way to delete the links so that they just render as text.

Thank you for any and all responses.

*EDIT*

I have attempted to add several js solutions targeting the linked columns, as well as attempted to unlink the webpart title with both /none and #. While these solutions did not result in any errors, nothing resulted from them.

Thank you.

***EDIT***

I have realized that the links within the title column were due to it being the *linked to item* column, so I have rectified that. I have not, however, figured out how to remove the actual **column title** hyperlink to the item form.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please include screenshots? I am having trouble figuring out what you mean.

Comment: Hi @IMTheNachoMan

I will take screenshots when not on my work computer.

To be a little more clear, the actual COLUMN HEADERS themselves in the datasheet view are opening the item edit form. I'm a little perplexed as to why this might be.

I will try and upload a gif or something ASAP.